# Two AWT threads despite runLater?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

When I run my program on a Raspberry Pi, I get this from the log:

```
[THREAD ID=AWT-EventQueue-2]24 Jan 2014 12:56:21 DEBUG PFrameClient - 2 - performAnimation
 [THREAD ID=AWT-EventQueue-1]24 Jan 2014 12:56:24 DEBUG PFrameClient - 3 - entering onAnimationFinished
 [THREAD ID=AWT-EventQueue-2]24 Jan 2014 12:56:24 DEBUG PFrameClient - 1 - entering performAnimation
 [THREAD ID=AWT-EventQueue-1]24 Jan 2014 12:56:24 DEBUG PFrameClient - 4 - leaving onAnimationFinished
```

...but all the code that does the logging is wrapped in SwingUtilities.invokeLater calls (see below).

On Mac and Windows all the calls are logged as being in one thread.

Can somebody clue me in, and help me figure out what's wrong?

(The timer in onAnimationFinished is used to avoid a deadlock situation)

```
public void performAnimation(final Animation animation) throws RemoteException {
    final Animation.Observer obs = this;
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            logger.debug("1 - entering performAnimation");
            animation.perform(world, obs);
            logger.debug("2 - performAnimation");
        }
    });
}

public void onAnimationFinished(final int tag) {
    final Timer t = new Timer();
    final TimerTask r = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    logger.debug("3 - entering onAnimationFinished");


                    templateMethodOnAnimationFinished(tag);
                    try {
                        master.animationIsFinished(tag);
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                    logger.debug("4 - leaving onAnimationFinished");
                    logger.debug("----");
                }
            });

        }

    };
    t.schedule(r, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaaaaaand it's because the original Swing frame was not created on the Swing main thread using invokeLater.

TIL always to check the main method of my program, when coding for Swing.